# CSS alignment textarea a

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've a textarea and a button-stylized link as :

```
__________________
|                 |
|                 |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯  ______
                     |send|
                     ------
```

I would like horizontal align.

My HTML :

```
<form method="post" action="">                  
    <div>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Send</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

My CSS :

```
textarea {
    display: inline;

    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius : 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

form a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -10px;

    background: #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius : 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: You want them to align like on the picture?

Comment: Are you trying to put the A under the textarea, or next to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a float attribute? For example, in addition to your current CSS styles, append the following styles.

```
textarea {
  float:left;
}

form a {
  float:left;
}
```